# Find data value from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want JQuery function to return me the value inside the `'data-tabconfig'`

```
<li class="tab-add" data-tabconfig="#{layoutBean.maxTabs}">
```

I can easily get it if I call onclick function.

```
$(this).attr('data-tabConfig');
```

But I don't want to get it on click,I want to get it on bodyload().

I tried with `.find()` but I couldnt get it working

This was my attempt `$('li').find().attr('data-tabConfig');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $('li.tab-add').attr('data-tabconfig');
//OR

       $('li.tab-add').data('tabconfig');

    });
```

Comment: If it is helpfull then you can accept this answer or someone else.So,we can close this question.Don;t forget to upvote :p

Answer (score 2):

To get the contents of the attribute data-id (like in ) you have to use

```
$('li.tab-add').attr("data-tabconfig") // will return the string 123
```

or .data() (if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3)

```
$('li.tab-add').data("tabconfig") // will return the string 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) to get the element with a particular attribute. Although wrap it within [document ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to run after elements are loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var val = $('li[data-tabConfig]').attr('data-tabConfig');
    // do the rest
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.tab-add').attr('data-tabConfig');
});
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/1281/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get with your own attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = $('body').find('li.tab-add:first').attr('data-tabConfig');
});
```